# Pandas read_csv doesn't parse correctly csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read csv file and then convert it to data frame but i don't know why all the columns are shown in the first row and even with separator or delimiter either without them I am not able to separate them.  I don't know how to change code in order to have correct result? 
Here is one line of file

```
1330-5235-5560-xxxxx,"Jan 1, 2017",12:35:13 AM PST,,Charge,,Smart Plan (Calling & Texting),com.xxx,1,unlimited_usca_tariff_and,astar-y3,US,NC,27288,USD,4.99,0.950333,EUR,9.49
```

[image]

Comment: if removed `delimeter`, same problem?

Comment: because default separator `sep=','`

Comment: yes, It's the same exactly. I've put exact line of csv for trying.

Comment: data are confidental?

Comment: It's the same template and pattern as real but they are not real one. I removed by the way 2 names. sorry.

Comment: Can anonymize data and send me file to my email in my profile? Because without your real file it is problematic found what is wrong.

Comment: Ofcource, thx for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136866/discussion-between-maryam-pashmi-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need set `quoting` to `QUOTE_NONE` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import csv

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

#sum some columns 
df['Transaction Date'] = df['Description'] + df['Transaction Date']
#create column from index
df['Description'] = df.index

#remove " from values
df['Description'] = df['Description'].str.strip('"')
df['Transaction Date'] = df['Transaction Date'].str.strip('"')
df['Amount (Merchant Currency)'] = df['Amount (Merchant Currency)'].str.strip('"')
                                                                   .astype(float)

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df.head(1))


            Description Transaction Date Transaction Time  Tax Type  \
0  8330-5235-5560-88882       Jan 8 2084  82:35:83 AM PST       NaN   

  Transaction Type  Refund Type                    Product Title Product id  \
0           Charge          NaN  Smart Plan ( Calling & Texting)  com.fight   

   Product Type              Sku Id  Hardware Buyer Country Buyer State  \
0             8  unlimited_usca_and  astar-y3            US          NC   

  Buyer Postal Code Buyer Currency  Amount (Buyer Currency)  \
0             24288            USD                     9.99   

   Currency Conversion Rate Merchant Currency  Amount (Merchant Currency)  
0                   0.95028               EUR                        9.49
```