# CSV file not properly entering dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, trading

I am trying to import CSV files downloaded from Yahoo Finance into pandas as dataframes. The US stocks work, for example tickers SPY or FB, but stocks listed on Canadian exchanges don't, for example SU or CRE. The CSV files from Yahoo appear exactly the same when opened in a text editor:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
```

With each being formatted exactly the same (eg. dates are YYYY-MM-DD for each.) But I am getting this error: "ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar" any time I try a Canadian ticker. This is my code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def symbol_to_path(symbol, base_dir="data"):
    """Return CSV file path given ticker symbol."""
    return os.path.join(base_dir, "{}.csv".format(str(symbol)))

def get_data(symbols, dates):
    """Read stock data (adjusted close) for given symbols from CSV files."""
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=dates)
    if 'SPY' not in symbols:  # add SPY for reference, if absent
        symbols.insert(0, 'SPY')

    for symbol in symbols:
        df_temp = pd.read_csv(symbol_to_path(symbol), index_col='Date',
                              parse_dates=True,
                              usecols=['Date', 'Adj Close'],
                              na_values=['nan'])
        df_temp = df_temp.rename(columns={'Adj Close': symbol})
        print df_temp
        df = df.join(df_temp)
        if symbol == 'SPY':  # drop dates SPY did not trade
            df = df.dropna(subset=["SPY"])

    return df


def plot_data(df, title="Stock prices", xlabel="Date", ylabel="Price"):
    """Plot stock prices with a custom title and meaningful axis labels."""
    ax = df.plot(title=title, fontsize=12)
    ax.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    ax.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    plt.show()


def compute_daily_returns(df):
    """Compute and return the daily return values."""
    # TODO: Your code here
    # Note: Returned DataFrame must have the same number of rows
    # daily_returns = df.copy() # copy DataFrame to match size and column names
    # compute daily returns for row 1 onwards
    # daily_returns[1:] = (df[1:] / df[:-1].values) - 1
    # daily_returns.ix[0, :] = 0 # set daily returns for row 0 to 0

    # Another way to compute daily returns using .shift
    daily_returns = (df / df.shift(1)) - 1
    return daily_returns

def compute_cumulative_returns(df):
    cumulative_return = df.copy()
    cumulative_return = (df.iloc[:] / df.iloc[0]) - 1
    return cumulative_return


def normalize_data(df):
  # Normalize stock prices by dividing by the first row of the dataframe
  return df / df.iloc[0,:]

def test_run():
    # Read data
    dates = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31')
    # SPY, FB both work perfectly, SU breaks
    symbols = ['SPY', 'FB', 'SU']
    df = get_data(symbols, dates)

    plot_data(df)
    plot_data(normalize_data(df), title="Normalized return", ylabel="Normalized return")

    # Compute daily returns
    daily_returns = compute_daily_returns(df)
    plot_data(daily_returns, title="Daily returns", ylabel="Daily returns")

    # Compute cumulative returns
    cumulative_returns = compute_cumulative_returns(df)
    plot_data(cumulative_returns, title="Cumulative returns", ylabel = "Cumulative return", xlabel = "Time")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_run()
```

This code assumes that in the directory it is being ran, there is a folder named 'data' (without the quotes) containing CSV files named the same as the tickers being supplied in the 'symbols' array in test_run(). Data downloaded from here for SU:

https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/SU.TO/history?period1=789894000&period2=1516604400&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d

And here from SPY:

https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY/history?period1=728290800&period2=1516604400&interval=1d&filter=history&frequency=1d

I know that SPY started trading before SU, but FB also started trading much later than SPY and works with the code provided.

Comment: Try this ===>>  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509808/pandas-read-csv-doesnt-parse-correctly-csv-file  OR   http://cmdlinetips.com/2018/01/7-tips-to-read-a-csv-file-as-pandas-data-frame/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SU.TO.csv file contains rows with 'null' values.

For example on line 68:

```
1995-04-13,2.383130,2.383130,2.359380,2.359380,0.963797,3283200
1995-04-14,null,null,null,null,null,null
1995-04-17,2.390620,2.390620,2.359380,2.359380,0.963797,600000
```

So you will have to take care of that in your code.

---

Maybe you can use `na_values=['null']` instead of `na_values=['nan']`?

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I did na_values=['null', 'nan'] so that it doesn't break in case of either.